# Can fibrations be described via universal morphisms?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, universal-property, fibration

Jacobs defines Cartesian morphisms and fibrations in Definition 1.1.3 of [this document.](https://people.mpi-sws.org/%7Edreyer/courses/catlogic/jacobs.pdf)

In other places in the text he uses phrases like "the universal property of this lifting." This made me wonder, *can Cartesian morphisms or fibrations be defined in terms of [universal morphisms ?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property)* If so, I'd be very interested to know how.

Comment: Yes, check this out: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cartesian+morphism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a functor $p\colon E\to B$, for each object $Y$ it has an associated functor $p/Y\colon E/Y\to B/pY$ from the category whose objects are morphisms in $E$ with codomain $Y$ and whose morphisms are commutative triangles in $E$, to the category whose objects are morphisms in $B$ with codomain $pY$ and whose morphisms are commutative triangles in $B$.

Given a morphism $g\colon Z\to Y$, considered as an object of $E/Y$, a morphism $w\colon (p/Y)g\to u$ in $B/pY$ is a morphism $w\colon pZ\to I$ such that $u\circ w=pg$.

A morphism $k\colon (p/Y)f\to u$ is then universal if for every other morphism $w\colon (p/Y)g\to u$ there is a unique morphism $h\colon Z\to X$ such that $w=k\circ (p/Y)h$.

We see then that $f\colon X\to Y$ satisfying $pf=u$ is Cartesian precisely when the identity morphism $\mathrm{id}_u\colon (p/Y)f\to u$ from the functor $p/Y\colon E/Y\to B/pY$ to $pf$ is universal.

P.S. The notion of a Grothendieck fibration is not stable under equivalence of categories. Functors equivalent to Grothendieck fibrations are the so-called Street fibrations, and can be characterizes by the condition that every object $u$ in $B/pY$ admits a universal morphism $(p/Y)f\to u$ that is an isomorphism.